# The extension of vector bundle over Hermitian manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Bando-Siu's paper  [Stable sheaves and Einstein-Hermitian metrics](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~siu/bando_joint_paper/index.html)

Theorem 2  Let $(E,h)$ be a holomorphic vector bundle with a Hermitian metric $h$ defined on a Kähler manifold $(Y,\omega)$ outside a closed subset with locally finite Hausdorff measure of real co-dimension 4. Assume that its curvature tensor $F$ is locally square integrable on $Y$, then

$E$ extends to the whole space $Y$ as a reflexive sheaf $\mathcal{E}$

My question is that Is the extension theorem right for Hermitian manifold?

Thank you!

Comment: You may assume $\omega$ is Gauduchon metric

Comment: Moverover, you must impose some positivity notion on initial hermitian metric such that when you run the Hermitian Yang Mills flow , the solution remain positive.

Comment: Than you for your comments. I wonder why I should assume $\omega$ to be Gauduchon.

Comment: OK, It seems you need to read a lot of information on non-Kahler geometry. Anyway there is a thesis a person claimed that he has proven your question. There is a mistake on it.

Comment: In the definition of degree of sheaf when it is equipped with Gauduchon metric then it is well defined since it is independent of a choice of metric

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, you are right. I know degree being well-defined needs $\omega$ to be Gauduchon. However,here there is no need for the  degree to be well-defined. Can you offer me some references about the non-Kahler geometry.

Comment: Bando-Siu solved it in Kahler case up to $C^{1,\alpha}$ estimate, Even for Kahler setting it is open yet.

Comment: Sorry for the previous comments, I didn't read your question carefully, I thought you want to extend Bando-Siu paper for Hermitian manifold. So for that case for the definition of stability we need Gauduchon metric. It seems your questions is nice

Comment: See this paper , main theorem https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01444234 . In fact The main idea of Siu-Bano paper about the extension of Hitchin Kobayashi correspondence is your question in Kahler case and Siu wrote in his paper without correctly credit to paper and PhD thesis of Shevchishin  anyway

Comment: It doesn't matter.  Great, thank you for your kind comments, I will look at his paper carefully.